# dirPagination not working

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, pagination, dirpagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD16H.png)I am trying to implement pagination with dirPaginate. I have gotten search and sort working, but I can't figure out why pagination is not functioning? please point out how I can correct this.

This is my code:

```
   <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Transport View</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>


 <div id="banner" style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin- right:auto; display:block;">

    <img src="http://intranet.gfhs.local/stlc_trans/STLC-Tree-Logo-PACE.png">

 </div>

 <br> <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Search</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control"   placeholder="Search">
    </div>
</form>


<div ng-controller="decontroller">
<br><table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>

<tr><td></td><th style="text-align:center;" colspan="5"><h4>Attendance</h4> </th><td></td><th style="text-align:center;" colspan="7"><h4>PCS Hours</h4></th></tr>    
<tr>

<td ng-click="sort('ParticipantName')"><b>Participant Name</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='ParticipantName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_mo')"><b>Mon</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_mo'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
</td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_tu')"><b>Tue</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_tu'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_we')"><b>Wed</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_we'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_th')"><b>Thu</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_th'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('attendance_fr')"><b>Fr</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='attendance_fr'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('Lanyard_Status')"><b>Lanyard Status</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='Lanyard_Status'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>


<td ng-click="sort('PCS Monday Hours')"><b>PCS Mon</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Monday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Tuesday Hours')"><b>PCS Tue</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Tuesday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Wednesday Hours')"><b>PCS Wed</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Wednesday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Thursday Hours')"><b>PCS Thu</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Thursday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span> </td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Friday Hours')"><b>PCS Fr</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Friday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Saturday Hours')"><b>PCS Sat</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Saturday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

<td ng-click="sort('PCS Sunday Hours')"><b>PCS Sun</b>
<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='PCS Sunday Hours'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></td>

</tr> 

<tbody>
<tr dir-paginate="n in list_data| orderBy:sortKey:reverse |itemsPerPage:5|  filter:search track by $index">

    <td>{{n.ParticipantName}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_mo==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_tu==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_we==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_th==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.attendance_fr==0?"":"x"}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Lanyard_Status}}</td>
    <!--<td>{{n.AssistiveDevices}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Lanyard}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Wheelchair_Van}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.VanComments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Pick_Up_Time}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Drop_Off_Time}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.TransportationComments}}</td>-->
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Monday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Tuesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Wednesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Thursday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Friday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Saturday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.PCS_Hours_Sunday}}</td>
    <!--<td>{{n.stlcid}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.physical_address}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.disenrolled}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.deceased}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Wheelchair_Van_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_240_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_360}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Transit_Van_360_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Subaru_Impreza}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.Subaru_Impreza_comments}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.address_lat}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.address_long}}</td>-->
    <!--<td>{{n.phone}}</td>--> 
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<dir-pagination-controls
   max-size="5"
   direction-links="true"
   boundary-links="true" >
</dir-pagination-controls>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller('decontroller', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.list_data=[];
    $http.get("<?php echo site_url("index.php/transport/ajax_load_data")?>").success(function(result){
        console.log("GOT DATA: "+JSON.stringify(result));
        $scope.list_data=result;
    });

    $scope.sort = function(keyname){
    $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
}

});


</script>

</body>
[console log errors][1]</html>
```

Comment: Hi. You asked me to answer this, but you should provide the error from the browser console, otherwise it is hard to figure out what is going wrong.

I assume there is some error, since your screenshot shows that angular is not interpolating the template values. Please amend the question with this info. Also, you might want to cut out some of those `<th>` rows just for the sake of keeping your code readable and to-the-point.

Comment: Thanks for the response i have edited code and added console log error image. Thank you again.

Comment: I think the problem is when i add the 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination' it seems to go wrong from that point,

Answer (score 0):

From the error message in the console (404) it looks like it might be a problem with the location of the `dirPagination.js` file.

In your script tag you point to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/dirPagination.js"></script>`

Here is a guess - the leading slash is causing the browser to look in the server root. I'm not sure if this is what you want or not. Try removing that leading slash and see if that fixes it. Failing that, just double check the location of the dirPagination.js script on your web server.